# what happens when we have two classes with same names in java?

Tags: java

I have the following files in the same directory.

here is my code

boys.java

```
import java.io.*;

public class boys
{
    String name;
    int age;

    boys()
    {
        this.name="empty";
        this.age=0;
    }

    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Name =" + name + "\nAge ="+ age );
    }

}
```

girls.java

```
import java.io.*;

class girls 
{
    String name;
    int age;

    girls(String name,int age)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }

    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Name="+name+"Age="+age);
    }
 }
```

group.java`

```
    import java.io.*;


class boys
{
    int rollno;

    boys()
    {
        rollno=100;
        System.out.printf("%d",rollno);
    }
}

public class group
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        boys b = new boys();

        girls g = new girls("sri divya",21);        

        g.display();
    }
}
```

And here are my question after using the javac command I have only one boys.class file why? and

after the command 'java group' shows me the result of the boys class inside the file group.java and not the boys class inside the file boys.java why?

what should I do if I want output of boys class inside boys.java inspite of having boys class in group.java?

why there is no error inspite of having two same class names?

someone pls help me

Comment: yes u can ... but those need to be in a different package

Comment: Class names in Java typically start with an uppercase letter. Don't break that naming convention for no reason.

Comment: Haven't I seen this question once already?

Comment: Why do you violate this simple, helpful recommendation to have only one top-level class per java source file? If you didn't, you wouldn't accidently define two classes with the same name. And it would be much easier for you to find the source of a class. Also, classes should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Also, please always place your classes in a package, even `com.rajan` will do - it means that you can import them and removes some odd behaviour of using the default package.

Comment: how you will distinguish both boys class if its in same package??think of it :D you should create both class in different package... and also follow the naming conventions

Comment: @Prashanth: my question is not about how do i differentiate its about how does the compiler differentiate without any errors? it gave me the output of boys class inside the group.java rather than boys class in boys.java is there any precedence over there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And here are my question after using the javac command I have only one
>   boys.class file why?

There can be only one class named `boys` in a given package, so the compiler will only generates one.

> after the command 'java group' shows me the result of the boys class
>   inside the file group.java and not the boys class inside the file
>   boys.java why?

When the compiler parse your `group.java` file he found two class and then compile them.

> what should I do if I want output of boys class inside boys.java
>   inspite of having boys class in group.java?

Remove the definition of `boys` from `group.java`.

> why there is no error inspite of having two same class names?

When you compile `group.java` the compiler found the `boys` class in it, so it don't need to look outside for its definition.

Defining a class at different places in the same package is a non-sense. Choose.

---

Now if you really want to replace the `boys` class with the one generated from the `boys.java` file you can:

- compile `group.java` (this will generate both `group.class` and
  `boys.class` from it)
- compile `boys.java` (this will *override* the    old `boys.class`
  with the one of `boys.java`)

It will work, but I would definitely not use such a construction.

Comment: Yunes: Thank you very much you gave me a clear answer for all my questions especially the last question

Answer (score 1):

If you name two classes the same, they should be in different packages, and when you want to use both of them in another class, you will have to reference (at least) one of them using its fully qualified name.

If two classes were in the same package with the same name, only one of them would be loaded by the `ClassLoader` -- which is most certainly not something you would want. This also causes an error in Eclipse, namely: `the type Boys is already defined`.

So if you can help it, you really should not name the classes the same way (and definitely not in the same package).

**Update:** I have tested the code, in this exact case the code runs even after throwing the compilation error, the `Boys` class is loaded by the `ClassLoader`, the one defined in the `Group` class is not. Actually, the `Boys` class in `Groups.java` is not even in the bytecode, it is removed during compilation.

PS: If you are writing Java code, you really should stick to conventions (upper camelcase classnames, camelcase methods, egyptian brackets etc.), especially if you are not the only one working on the code.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer i got some points but As u said i didnt get any error " the type Boys is already defined" may i know why?

Comment: Because it is false, there cannot be such a message!

Comment: Well it seems, it is just an Eclipse error then, edited my answer to reflect this.